# How can I move the contents of individual lines to the next line as an element?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have data in a text file, example:

```
CCDPA_ABUSE_INCIDENT_CODES
1|CODE|VARCHAR2 (1)|Y
2|DESCR|VARCHAR2 (40)|Y
CCDPA_ADULT_PS_INVESTIGATIONS
1|ID|NUMBER (10,0)|Y
2|CCDPACHRAPP_ID|NUMBER (10,0)|Y
CCDPA_APPLICANT_ALIASES
1|ID|NUMBER (10,0)|Y
2|CCDPACHRAPP_ID|NUMBER (10,0)|Y
```

I'm importing it into Python, and I need to for my script to do the following:

- Every line that is a string that begins with an alpha character needs to be prepended to the lines following it, as long as those lines begin with a numeral, until the next line that starts with an alpha character occurs
- I need a pipe character (|) inserted after the prepended string to divide it from the rest of the line
- The original line, the one that started with the alpha character, needs to be deleted.

When complete, the dataset should look like this:

```
CCDPA_ABUSE_INCIDENT_CODES|1|CODE|VARCHAR2 (1)|Y
CCDPA_ABUSE_INCIDENT_CODES|2|DESCR|VARCHAR2 (40)|Y
CCDPA_ADULT_PS_INVESTIGATIONS|1|ID|NUMBER (10,0)|Y
CCDPA_ADULT_PS_INVESTIGATIONS|2|CCDPACHRAPP_ID|NUMBER (10,0)|Y
CCDPA_APPLICANT_ALIASES|1|ID|NUMBER (10,0)|Y
CCDPA_APPLICANT_ALIASES|2|CCDPACHRAPP_ID|NUMBER (10,0)|Y
```

The final product should be exported as a .CSV to be imported into Excel.  I can't figure out if I should use a pandas dataframe, or keep it as a text file.  How do I accomplish this?

Comment: This seems like a simple loop that read the file line by line. If it begins with a letter, save the line into a variable. Otherwise, add that variable as a prefix to the current line, and write that combined line to the output file.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one of the options :

```
df = pd.read_fwf("file.txt", header=None)
​
m = df[0].str[0].str.isalpha() #is the row starts with an alphabetic ?
​
out = df.assign(tmp=df[0].where(m).ffill()).loc[~m][["tmp", 0]].agg("|".join, axis=1)

#out.to_excel("output.xlsx", header=False, index=False) #uncomment to make a spreadsheet
```

Output :

```
print(out)

1                  CCDPA_ABUSE_INCIDENT_CODES|1|CODE|VARCHAR2 (1)|Y
2                CCDPA_ABUSE_INCIDENT_CODES|2|DESCR|VARCHAR2 (40)|Y
4                CCDPA_ADULT_PS_INVESTIGATIONS|1|ID|NUMBER (10,0)|Y
5    CCDPA_ADULT_PS_INVESTIGATIONS|2|CCDPACHRAPP_ID|NUMBER (10,0)|Y
7                      CCDPA_APPLICANT_ALIASES|1|ID|NUMBER (10,0)|Y
8          CCDPA_APPLICANT_ALIASES|2|CCDPACHRAPP_ID|NUMBER (10,0)|Y
```